# NSOperationQueue feels slower than running code on main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsoperationqueue

I'm making a tweak (that displays some images from web) for `ios` and i'm trying to use `NSOperationQueue`.
First i ran some code on the main thread to see how it looks like. It lasted ±5secs to show each image (UI froze).
Then i tried to use `NSOperationQueue` to run the same code but it lasted +10secs for each image (good thing is that the UI didn't freeze).
Any ideas? Is it just like that?

Comment: How do you download images? are you using initWithContentsOfURL or similar method?

Comment: i'm doing this: NSURL* url= [NSURL URLWithString:[_HTMLPage substringWithRange:range]];
                        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                        _image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Comment: When you load all the images on main thread then the collective download time is ~5 seconds and with operation queue the collective download time is ~10 seconds?

Comment: i'm loading multiples images, but 1 at a time. everytime the user touches the button it loads 1 more, and so on. but yeah, ±5 secs to get the image from the web and put it on an uiimageview on the main thread and +10secs to do that on the NSOperationQueue

Comment: (In case of OperationQueue)How you are updating your imageView? once the image is downloaded, are you calling performSelectorOnMainThread for updating imageView?

Comment: no. i'm just doing this when the tweak starts: invocationOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]  initWithTarget:self                                                                                    selector:@selector(showOperationQueue)                                                                                      object:nil]; and on "showOperationQueue" i run all the code to get the image and to put it on the uiimageview right there, on the same code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8743/discussion-between-ravin-and-pedro-vieira)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS the UI updation takes place on main thread, so once you are done with the operation queue you will need to inform main thread to update UI, but in your case as you said its updated but with delay.

You will need to call `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` from the operation(in the end, when data is downloaded), and in this main thread's selector you will perform UI updation.